# How to print the range of long double in C

Tags: c, double, range, long-integer

While trying to print the Max & Min range of Long Double in C I stumbled upon the problems with different format specifiers, so I tried every suggestion I could find in the following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<float.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(void)
{
    printf("Data Type    Memory Size                  Range\n");
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------     \n");
    printf("long double    %d bytes          %Lf to %Lf      |>(using %%Lf   as format specifier)\n",sizeof(long double),LDBL_MIN,LDBL_MAX);
    printf("long double    %d bytes          %lf to %lf      |>(using %%lf    as format specifier)\n",sizeof(long double),LDBL_MIN,LDBL_MAX);
    printf("long double    %d bytes                 %LG to %LG       |>    (using %%LG as format specifier)\n",sizeof(long double),LDBL_MIN,LDBL_MAX);
    printf("long double    %d bytes     %E to %E |>(using %%E as format   specifier)\n",sizeof(long double),LDBL_MIN,LDBL_MAX);
    printf("long double    %d bytes     %e to %e |>(using %%e as format specifier)\n",sizeof(long double),LDBL_MIN,LDBL_MAX);
    printf("long double    %d bytes          %llf to %llf      |>(using %%llF as format specifier)\n",sizeof(long double),LDBL_MIN,LDBL_MAX);
    printf("long double    %d bytes     %le to %le |>(using %%le as format specifier)\n",sizeof(long double),LDBL_MIN,LDBL_MAX);
    printf("long double    %d bytes          %f to %f      |>(using %%f as format specifier)\n",sizeof(long double),LDBL_MIN,LDBL_MAX);
    printf("-------------------------------------------------------------\n");
    printf("NOTE: I'm trying to find the range of long double!\n");
    printf("      But none of the format specifiers seems to work! Please Help...\n");
    return 0;
}
```

But the output is:
[image: screenshot]

According to https://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_data_types.htm

memory size of long double: 10 bytes (I know this might vary)

range of long double: 3.4E-4932 to 1.1E+4932

*But the output of my code is no where near 3.4E-4932 to 1.1E+4932. But Why?

Comment: 3.4E-4932 is very much near 0.

Comment: `%d` takes an `int`, not a `size_t`. `%f`/`%e` take a `double`, not a `long double`. `%llf` is invalid. `%lf`/`%le` are equivalent to `%f`/`%e` (starting with C99, that is; before that they had undefined behavior).

Comment: Post text as text, not pictures of text.

Comment: Passing format specifiers that don't match the variable types is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Compiler warnings are not fully enable.

Many compilers point out `printf()` specifier mis-match

---

Specifier mis-match with `long double` and `size_t` (the return type of `sizeof`)  [@melpomene](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1848654/melpomene)

> `L` Speciﬁes that a following `a`, `A`, `e`, `E`, `f`, `F`, `g`, or `G` conversion speciﬁer applies to a `long double` argument.  C11dr §7.21.6.1  7

```
// wrong specifiers
printf("long double    %d bytes     %E to %E |>(using %%E as format   specifier)\n",
    sizeof(long double),LDBL_MIN,LDBL_MAX);
// Correct specifiers
printf("long double    %zu bytes     %LE to %LE |>(using %%E as format   specifier)\n",
    sizeof(long double),LDBL_MIN,LDBL_MAX);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man! 
%LE solved the problem about the range, but what is %zu? and it prints nothing! when I change it to %d it conflicts with %LE

Comment: If you are not using a `C99` compliant  compiler, the posted solution may not work. Try `printf("long double    %u bytes\n", (unsigned) sizeof(long double));`

Answer (score 0):

Here's a start

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libquadmath/#toc-GNU-Free-Documentation-License-1

```
CC=gcc

CFLAGS=-lm -ll -lquadmath -mlong-double-128

DEPS = 

OBJ = sizeof.o 

%.o: %.c $(DEPS)

    $(CC) -c -o $@ $< $(CFLAGS)

sizeof: $(OBJ)

    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```